# Is there a standard pattern for verifying an async request is still needed?

Tags: multithreading, swift, mobile, closures

In mobile apps apps we can't (or should not) make network requests on the main thread.  We normally get the results of the request back via a callback or a closure that is executed on the main thread when the result is available.  Since the user may have moved on or the result may no longer be need, for example it may be an old request arriving out of order, we need to check that the action in the callback or closure should actually be executed based on the current state of the app.

In the case of iOS and swift I am planning on using closures so I am thinking of doing something like this for every request I make.

assume I have a method that looks something like this

```
func makeRequest(identifier: String, handler: (ident: String, result: ResultObject) -> Void) {
...
...
handler(identifier, result)
}
```

In addition to the handler that will be called when the result is available, I will pass in the value of an identifier, which in turn will be passed to the handler when it is called. The closure will capture a reference to the identifier when the request is created, so it be able to get the value that the reference holds at the time the handler is actually called.  So it would look something like this, where ident is the value that commandIdentifier was when the request was made, and commandIdentifier inside the closure will be the value when the closure is actually executed.

```
commandIdentifer = "some unique identifier"
makeRequest(commandIdentifer) { ident, result in
  if commandIdentifier == ident {
      // do something
  } else {
      // do something else
  }
}
```

I don't think there is anything special here, so my question is this:

---

Is this a general pattern, and if so where can I find any documentation on it?

I am particularly interested if there is some general way of creating the identifier and how to relate its reference in the main thread.

Also if I am total wrong and this not a good approach, I would like to hear that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used almost exactly that approach before. I use an integer identifier, and increment it when issuing a new request. That way if the pending request is superseded by a new one you can just drop the stale response on the floor.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, I was thinking of doing just that also.  I think what I will be using in the end , at least for this case is a "command object".  I am using the command pattern, so I realized I could pass the actual command the initiated the request into the handler and then check if that command is still set, has been replaced , or has been set to nil.  I will accept your answer, but I will also update my question or add an answer later today documenting what I am describing ... I would appreciate any comments you might have on that (when posted) since I really am in learning mode